# How do I deploy registry keys and values using WiX 3.0?

Tags: deployment, wix, windows-installer

If I want to create the registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\MyApp

with the string value

> EventMessageFile : C:\Path\To\File.dll

how do I define this in my [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) 3.0 WXS file? Examples of what the XML should look like is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to want to create an event log source. If that is the case, you should take a look at the [<EventSource>](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_eventsource.htm) element in the util extension.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this page](http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/RegistryValue_Element). An example would be:

```
<registry action="write" 
 root"HKLM" key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\MyApp"
 type="string" value="EventMessageFile : C:\Path\To\File.dll" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with this:

```
<Component Id="EventLogRegKeys" Guid="{my guid}">
    <RegistryKey Id="Registry_EventLog" Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\MyApp" Action="create">
        <RegistryValue Id="Registry_EventLog_EventSourceDll" Action="write" KeyPath="yes" Name="EventMessageFile" Type="string" Value="C:\Path\To\File.dll" />
    </RegistryKey>  
</Component>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to refer to File.dll using file reference syntax, to ensure that the actual path it's installed to is used. Use `[#filekey]`, where `filekey` is the `Id` of the `File` element describing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following under DirectoryRef --> Directory...

<Component Id="RegisterAddReferencesTab32" Guid="D9D01248-8F19-45FC-B807-093CD6765A60">  <RegistryValue Action="write" Id="RegInstallDir32" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\MyApp" Root="HKLM" Type="string" Value="C:\Path\To\File.dll" /></Component>